# Mandar valor de checkbox a una base de datos y un icono a una tabla

Tags: php, html, mysql

Mi duda es al momento de realizar los checkbox va todo bien estos checkbox estan en agregarcliente.php:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Cl" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="Cl" value="1" />
   <label> &nbsp; Cliente </label>

<br>

<input type="hidden" name="Prov" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="Prov" value="1" />

<label> &nbsp; Proveedor </label>

<br>

<input type="hidden" name="Des" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="Des" value="1"  />
<label> &nbsp; Destinatario </label>

 </div>
</div>
```

como pueden observar realizo dos input ya que al momento no seleccionar el checkbox automáticamente manda el valor 0 y por el contrario si esta seleccionado el valor 1 manda dicho valor ala base de datos, todo bien hasta ahí la cuestión es que me gustaría recibir en esta otra pagina llamada cliente.php que decida si es valor es 0 mande un icono de una "x" a una table class que tengo en cliente.php y si esta bien que mande un "✔" tengo pensado usar el glyphicon, en el siguiente codigo muestro como almaceno los datos de la tabla de mysql dentro de cada celda de la table class de la pagina cliente.php

```
 <tr>

<td class="text-center"><?php echo remove_junk($cliente['cliente']); ?>
?>
</td>

<td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($cliente['proveedor']); ?> 
</td>

<td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($cliente['destinatario']);? 
> 
</td>
```

Lo que aun no logro hacer es un tipo de condición  en la cual verifique que si lo almacenado en la tabla de mysql es "1" mande "✔" a la tabla de cliente.php y que cuando sea un "0" mande "x" a la misma tabla de cliente.php.

```
<tbody> 
<?php foreach ($clientes as $cliente):?> 
<tr> 
<td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($cliente['cliente']); ?> 
</td> 
<td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($cliente['proveedor']); ?> 
</td> 
<td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($cliente['destinatario']);?> 
</td> 
</tr> 
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</tbody>
```

este es el código que utilizo para llenar la tabla que tengo hecha en cliente.php

```
 <table class="table table-bordered"> 
 <thead> 
 <tr> 
 <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Cliente </th> 
 <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Proveedor </th> 
 <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Destinatario </th> 
 </tr>
```

esta es la tabla que comento que tengo en cliente.php a donde va los datos que comente anteriormente.

Espero haberme expresado bien y agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar que pasen buen dia

Buenos dias probe con este código:

```
<?php if ($cliente['cliente'] == 1) echo "Tu código con el icono ✔" ?>
```

y gracias a este código me funciono pero solo cuando se esta presionado el checkbox pero no me manda nada cuando dicho checkbox no esta presionado quiero creer que es por que me falta la otra condición pero ya probe con else y nada

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Guillermo, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento debes modificar tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado e investigado, sigue el consejo de @Ferni "editar tu pregunta y añadir los cambios y avances que hayas realizado en tu código",  saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Al extraer los datos de tu base de datos puedes simplemente comprobarlos con un `if ... else`.

```
<?php
if ($cliente['cliente'] == 1) {
    ?><td class="text-center">//Tu código con el icono ✔</td><?
} else {
    ?><td class="text-center">//Tu código con el icono X</td><?
}
?>
```

Si el resultado es 1, entonces se usará el código HTML con el cual muestras el icono ✔, en caso contrario se usará el otro.

Comment: hola ya intente tu código pero al parecer hay un problema 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH)

<?php foreach ($clientes as $cliente):?>
              <tr>
        <td class="text-center">   <?php echo remove_junk($cliente['cliente']); ?>
?>
<td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($cliente['proveedor']); ?></td>

<td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($cliente['destinatario']); ?></td>

<?php endforeach; ?>

Sustitui
<td class="text-center">   <?php echo remove_junk($cliente['cliente']); ?>
?> 
Por el código que me comentaste

Comment: Te sobra un `?>` después de `remove_junk($cliente['cliente']); ?> ?>`. Sería de ayuda ver el bucle entero para ver si hay algún error de sintaxis.

Comment: <tbody>
<?php foreach ($clientes as $cliente):?>

 <tr>

<td class="text-center">   <?php echo remove_junk($cliente['cliente']); ?></td>

 
<td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($cliente['proveedor']); ?></td>

<td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($cliente['destinatario']); ?></td>

</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
 </tbody>

este es el que utilizo para llevar llenar la tabla que tengo hecha en cliente.php

Comment: <table class="table table-bordered">
 <thead>
 <tr>

                 <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Cliente </th>

                  <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Proveedor </th>

                   <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Destinatario </th>

              </tr> 

esta es la tabla que comento que tengo en cliente.php a donde va los datos que comente anteriormente

Comment: <?php
 if ($cliente['cliente'] == 1)
echo "Tu código con el icono ✔"
?>

probé con este código y funciono solo cuando se esta presionado el checkbox  algo curioso fue de que al no tenerlo presionado no me manda nada quiero creer que es por que me falta la otra condición pero ya probe con else y nada

Comment: Te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y añadir los cambios y avances que hayas realizado en tu código en vez de añadir fragmentos del mismo como comentario.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($cliente['cliente'] == 1) {$showme = ‘<span class=“fa fa check”> </span>’;} 
    else if ($cliente['cliente'] == 0) {$showme = ‘<span class=“fa fa times”> </span>’;}
```

Solo imprime la variable $showme y ya esta lo que buscas

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/297348)

Comment: Respondí desde un celular y sale la respuesta cortada, sigue criticando!